# I want to run my code, but terminal tells index out of bounds. Probably, because of ArrayList methode get ot smth like this

Tags: java, compilation, visual-studio-code, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm trying to run my code.
But terminal tells:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
    at CF455A.main(CF455A.java:25)
```

25th string is:  `game.remove(game.get(max+1));`
My code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

public class CF455A {
 public static void main(String args[]) throws java.lang.Exception {
     Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
     int n = in.nextInt();
     int max = 0;
     ArrayList<Integer> game = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        int t = in.nextInt();
        game.add(i, t);
    }

    int counter = 0;

    while(game.size()>0){
        for(int j = 0; j < game.size(); j++){
            if(max <= (int)game.get(j)){max=j;}
            for(int i = 0; i < game.size(); i++){
                counter = counter + (int)game.get(max);
                game.remove(game.get(max));
                game.remove(game.get(max+1));
                game.remove(game.get(max-1));
            }
        }

    }
    System.out.print(counter);
    in.close();
}
```

}
I think this happends because of ArrayList or methodes like `game.get();` or `game.remove();`.
I just wanted to change a value of one of the elements of ArrayList

List item

Comment: You have a list with one object. A list with one object does not have an object at index 1. So your logic of calculating the index is wrong. I would suggest to edit it accordingly :) Good speed.

Comment: Whatever you are trying to do here, it's a good time to learn to use your IDEs builtin debugger and step through your code.

Comment: @Yerassly please look at my answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to logic :- 
if i give input as :- 5 1 2 3 4 5 
then first pass :- 
game.size() = 5;
while condition true -> and tries to remove the item at index (1,0,-1).So it fails for (-1) **IndexOutOfBounds**.
Please do the null check as follows :-

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

public class TestMemberOuter1 {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws java.lang.Exception {
        Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
        int n = in.nextInt();
        int max = 0;
        ArrayList<Integer> game = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            int t = in.nextInt();
            game.add(i, t);
        }

        int counter = 0;

        while(game.size()>0){
            for(int j = 0; j < game.size(); j++){

                if(max <= (int)game.get(j))
                {
                    max=j;
                }
                for(int i = 0; i < game.size(); i++){
                    counter = counter + (int)game.get(max);
                    if(max < game.size() )
                    {
                        game.remove(game.get(max));
                    }
                    if(max+1 <  game.size() )
                    {
                        game.remove(game.get(max+1));
                    }

                    if(max-1 > 0 )
                    {
                        game.remove(game.get(max-1));
                    }

                }
            }

        }
        System.out.print(counter);
        in.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any `null` put  in the ArrayList, so the check `!= null` seems confusing to me.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Just more focus on boundary conditions

Comment: Oh,thanks. I need to be more carefull in work with Arrays in Java next time!

Comment: Good explanation @HasnainAliBohra